# Tower Property for Expectations and Stopping Times

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega,(\mathcal{F_t})_{t\geq0},P)$ be a filtered proability space with  $X\in L^1(P)$ and two stopping times $S$ and $T$.

Show that

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_T)|\mathcal{F}_S)=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_{S\wedge T}),~P-a.s.
\end{equation*}

I am a bit stuck on this and tried spilting it into 2 cases, namely on $\{S\leq T\}$ and it's complement and usng the fact that $\mathcal{F}_s\cap\mathcal{F}_T=\mathcal{F}_{S\wedge T}$ but don't get far.

So any help is most welcomed and needs.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\{T\leq S\}$, $\{S>T\}\in\mathcal{F}_T\cap\mathcal{F}_S$ and for any $A\in\mathcal{F}_T$ we have $A\cap\{T\leq S\}\in\mathcal{F}_S$.  Therefore  $A\cap\{T\leq S\}\in\mathcal{F}_T\cap\mathcal{F}_S$.  Thus by the definition on conditional expectation for any $A\in\mathcal{F}_T$,

$E(1_A.1_{\{T\leq S\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge S})) =E(1_{A\cap\{T\leq S\}}X) 
 = E(1_{A\cap\{T \leq S\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_T))=E(1_{A}.1_{\{T \leq S\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_T))$.

Thus $1_{\{T\leq S\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_{T})=1_{\{T\leq S\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge S}))$  $-(*)$.

So then,

$1_{\{T\leq S\}}E(E(X|\mathcal{F}_{T}|\mathcal{F}_S))=E(1_{\{T\leq S\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_T)|\mathcal{F}_S) =E(1_{T\leq S\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge S})|\mathcal{F}_S)=1_{\{T\leq S\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_{S\wedge T})$.

Switching the roles of $S$ and $T$ and replacing $X$ by $E(X|\mathcal{F}_T)$ in $(*)$ we similarly get,

$1_{\{S<T\}}E(E(X|\mathcal{F}_T)|\mathcal{F}_S)=1_{\{S<T\}}E(E(X|\mathcal{F}_T)|\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge S})=1_{\{S< T\}}E(X|\mathcal{F}_{T \wedge S})$.

Comment: If (as you claim) $A \cap \{S \leq T\} \in \mathcal{F}_T$ and $A \cap \{S>T\} \in \mathcal{F}_T$, then obviously $$A = (A \cap \{S \leq T\}) \cup (A \cap\{S>T\}) \in \mathcal{F}_T$$ for any $A \in \mathcal{F}_S$. This would actually imply $\mathcal{F}_S = \mathcal{F}_T$.

Comment: Yes that is an oversight, so the mistake is with $A\cap\{S>T\}$, but it is certainly true that for any $A\in\mathcal{F}_S$ we have $A\cap\{S\leq T\}\in\mathcal{F}_T$. I will rethink this,do you have any suggestions to rectify this? The suggestion of the questioner to split the integral seems now not to be a viable option.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have an idea how to fix it. I'm not even sure whether the claim holds true.

Comment: I'm now found this question on some online notes here https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/p.j.c.spreij/onderwijs/master/sisyllabus.pdf   It looks like this claim is correct, I will ask around to see why, do you have any new takes on this?

Comment: I have rethought the problem and tried another approach please could you check to see you agree with it.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do so; just give me some more time. :)

Comment: Sure, I have edited the answer and replaced it with the new one.

Comment: Looks much better now. :)